# React 16 setState callback causes Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app I used React setState's callback for setting new state after render.
When I upgraded React to `16.4.2`, `Maximum update depth exceeded` appeared because of the setState.

React 16 [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1660-october-23-2018):

> setState callback (second argument) now fires immediately after
>   componentDidMount / componentDidUpdate instead of after all components
>   have rendered.

Use:

```
someHandler() {
    this.setState({prop1: true}, () => {
        this.setState({prop1: false});
    });
},
```

How can I replace that use in a valid React 16 api, for setting state after render called?

Comment: Is the purpose of that to force a re-render? Why not just use `forceUpdate`? Also I doubt that code itself is triggering the recursion. I guess `someHandler` is called in `render` somehow?

Comment: Why not using `componentDidUpdate` instead of the second argument?

Comment: Also, does `someHnadler` get called from the render function?

Answer (score 0):

Your intention is a bit unclear, but I guess you would benefit from using the [React Lifecycle Methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

### If the goal is to set new state after **1st render:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({prop1:false});
}
```

#### If the goal is to set new state after **every render:**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.setState({prop1:false});
}
```

**Note:**
setState will cause an update, thus you will again encounter `Maximum update depth exceeded` since the method calls itself.
To prevent this, `componentDidUpdate`can have the parameters `componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps)` which you can use to prevent the infinite loop.
Your code would then probably look something like this.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
  if (prevState.prop1 !== this.state.prop1) {
     this.setState({prop1:false});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to an ***infinite loop***. you must be calling someHandler from somewhere inside render. Somehandler setstates which triggers a re-render and while re-rendering somehandler is called again. Thus, infinite loop. 
Try calling somehandler from somewhere inside the **Lifecycle hooks** like ComponentDidMount (or in case of functional/stateless components - `useEffect(()=>{body},[]))`